# Nested Json Access GSON

Tags: android, json, gson

I am switching from iOS to Android `GSON` and `Retrofit`.
So, for the JSON below

```
"distance" : {
     "text" : "102 ft",
     "value" : 31
}
```

I just want to access `value` from the `distance` object. Now, I know that I can make one `BaseModel` class and one `DistanceModelClass`. But I just want to take `value` only and that too in `BaseModel` class.

Can I do something like this -

```
@SerializedName("distance.value")
```

I mean I don't want to create an extra class name `DistanceModelClass`

In `iOS` it's possible using [ObjectMapper](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper#easy-mapping-of-nested-objects) Library

Comment: I'm quite not sure, I think you can't do like that. You'll set the response type for retrofit. Its unable to detect "distance.value" I guess

Comment: @Raghavendra I also think so. Searched a lot but didn't get any solution.

Comment: Although I can be wrong but one thing I learnt when working with retrofit was you have to create the whole structure to access something at the bottom of the structure. Once again, I can be wrong

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this when you get the result using the retrofit,

```
BaseModel Result = new Gson().fromJson(jsonResult.toString(), BaseModel.class);
String value = result.getValue();
```

Answer (score -1):

you can directly access value from distance just access value from BaseModel class

```
String valuee="";
if(receivedjson.getJSONObject("distance").has("value")){
valuee=json.getJSONObject("distance").getString("value");
}
```

here receivedjson is your received json object

Comment: OP about accessing in retrofit